# Bluetooth driver download

Tags: windows-7, drivers, 64-bit, troubleshooting, bluetooth

My Bluetooth peripheral device doesn't work, how can I fix it or download the driver?

My PC is a HP-Pavilion dv6, I am using Windows 7 X64.

Comment: What device are you trying to use?

Comment: Is bluetooth working on the laptop and you are just unable to connect?

Comment: Is bluetooth enabled? It will not work if it is turned off. Do other devices work?

Comment: I have an HP dv7 and I'm having the same problem.  I installed the bluetooth driver and it's working fine with my bluetooth mouse, however, my Vizio xvhtb100 headset is able to pair/connect but then windows says the drivers are not installed and when I try to update the drivers it can't find them on windows update.  I've had no luck trying various drivers I've found online.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the driver at HP's [support site](http://www8.hp.com/in/en/support-drivers.html). Click on Drivers and softwares and search with your laptop's exact model no.